# why is inner toggle not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

i have a toggle within a toggle but it is not working correctly. The toggle needs to show only when the div has the class 'clicked' (which is also toggled) but sometimes you can still click.. and also doesn't always work when it is clicked... i think i'm going at this completely wrong :S here is my code so far and fiddle to see what i mean - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xmgb85p5/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.timelineTile').click(function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        $('.selected').children().not(this).removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
        if ($('.selected').children().hasClass("clicked")) {
            $('.details').addClass('show');
        }
        if ($('.selected').children().hasClass("clicked")) {
            $(this).children('.item').click(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                $(this).siblings('.item-overlay').slideToggle('fast');
            });
        }
        if ($('.selected').children().not("clicked")) {
            $('.item-overlay').hide('fast');
        }
    });
});

$(document).click(function () {
    $('.timelineTile').removeClass('clicked');
    $('.details').removeClass('show');

    $('.item-overlay').hide('fast');
});
```

Comment: You are wiring up a click handler inside another event handler (never a good idea). It will add an extra function call every time that code runs.

Comment: The existing code seems to allow for multiple tiles in a selection. is that the case? Otherwise there is a lot of code that can be reduced.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand - it needs to be when the tile is clicked (goes red) - the click function 'item' (purple) works and the white 'item-overlay' can be toggled. But only the tile that is clicked not any others.

Comment: Your code allowed for multiple items in a tile. That did no seem necessary, so I removed all the redundant selectors and made the existing selectors target the specific open item (it was targetting  hidden items too, which is wasteful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what that example is meant to do, but you were wiring up a click handler inside a click handler. I have moved that outside and test the .selected ancestor for clicked children inside the new delegated click handler:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/xmgb85p5/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Click a tile
    $('.timelineTile').click(function (evt) {
        console.log(".timelineTile click");

        // Stop the click propogating
        evt.stopPropagation();

        // Remove clicked class from all other tiles and hide other overlays
        $('.timelineTile').not(this).removeClass('clicked').find('.item-overlay').hide("fast");

        // Toggle the current tile clicked class
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');

        // If we are clicked, show details
        if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
            $('.details', this).addClass('show');
        }
    }).on('click', '.item', function (e) {
        console.log(".item click");
        if ($(this).closest('.timelineTile').hasClass("clicked")) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).siblings('.item-overlay').slideToggle('fast');
        }
    });
});

$(document).click(function () {
    $('.timelineTile').removeClass('clicked');
    $('.details').removeClass('show');

    $('.item-overlay').hide('fast');
});
```

*If this is still not correct, please clarify the expected behaviour.*

Comment: thank you, but this doesn't toggle 'item-overlay' within the 'timelineTile'. I want when you open a 'timelinetile' you can then click on item which toggles the 'item-overlay' but only does this when timelinetile is open

Comment: thank you @TrueBlueAussie this is almost right! However the 'item-overlay' is still visible if another tile is clicked, it needs to close if another 'timelineTile' is clicked

Comment: I think I get it now. Updated to clear the click flags and close overlays of all *other* tiles.

Comment: Pretty much perfect! Thank you! - only problem was the item-overlay didn't close if you clicked on it but i've added that myself :-) thanks!